# Change the site configuration file to block listing out files in the directory - apache2 + Ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2

When I access a directory hosted by Apache that does not have a `index.php` file or similar, Apache lists the content of the directory for me. How can I block this? I'm using Apache2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

In the appropriate `<Directory>` stanza. For instance it may look like this:

```
<Directory /www/somefolder>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Change this into

```
<Directory /www/somefolder>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

If there is no `Options...` line, you can add one with the content `Options -Indexes` for any `<Directory...>` stanza. The options are separated by a space ().

Note the - in front of Indexes. This is also covered briefly in the [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) documentation.

The index are generated by [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html).

Comment: Thanks, should i make a new file with the content you provided in the example directory /var/www/filer?

Comment: No, the best solution is to edit your configuration.

Comment: I tried editing the apache2.conf file and restarted the server, but it didn't work. How can i access the folder trough localhost? When trying to access the folder in the browser, i get the custom error page.

Comment: @20_90 The default config file for default host is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.  You can also add this to the `<Directory /var/www/>` stanza of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Simply put a `-` in front of `Indexes`.